# How to access to IFrame DOM in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, angular6

How i can access to **IFrame DOM** in **angular 6** I can easily get iframe element - `this.hostElement.nativeElement.querySelector('iframe')`.

But i don't know how i can get some element inside this iframe, and, for example, change style attributes or change something in DOM. This iframe is from outside, from another domain.

Comment: It has been 3 years. @Yauheni were you able to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

`iframe` has it's own DOM tree (with own `document` and `window` elements) and you need to 'get' it's document to get inner elements.
To do so use [.contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow)

Eg.
`this.hostElement.nativeElement.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.document.querySelector()`

Comment: That won't work. The question says "This iframe is from outside, from another domain"

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work, because this iframe has url from another domain